# I inserted a metadata section on my Tumblr theme but it's not showing up. Is there anyway I can fix that?

Tags: html, tumblr

This is the code I have.

```
{block:Date}
<section class="metadata">
<ul class="index">
<li>Date Posted: <a href="{Permalink"><time datetime="{MonthNumberWithZero}-{DayOfMonthWithZero}-{Year}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}</time></a></li>

{block:ContentSource}
<li>{lang:Source}:<a href="{SourceURL}">{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceTitle}{/block:NoSourceLogo}
{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}"height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />{/block:SourceLogo}</a></li>
{/block:ContentSource} 

{block:NoteCount}<li><a class="notecount" href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a></li>{/block:NoteCount}

</ul>
</section>
{/block:Date}
```

And here is my Tumblr theme.

http://lt-colbylovesamanda.tumblr.com/

Is it me or does Tumblr miss that sometimes?

Comment: Again, when you don't post all of the code, it's near impossible to debug. We can't see your Tumblr theme code when visiting your blog. Are you using `{block:Date]` inside of the post block properly? Also, you're missing a closing `}` on the first `{Permalink}`.

Comment: I've changed what I've posted above and still nothing is showing up. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Post all of your code in a secret gist: https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

**NoteCount / NoteCountWithLabel**

The block `{block:NoteCount}` will only render if post has a note count higher than zero. If the count is zero, the block isn't rendered.

However, its possible to render the string `0 Notes`. To achieve this, simply remove the block and use the variable `{NoteCountWithLabel}`.

If you move the outer blocks `<li>` will render, and include a note count regardless:

```
{block:Date}
<section class="metadata">
<ul class="index">
<li>Date Posted: <a href="{Permalink"><time datetime="{MonthNumberWithZero}-     
{DayOfMonthWithZero}-{Year}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}</time></a></li>

<li><a class="notecount" href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel} 
</a></li>

</ul>
</section>
{/block:Date}
```

Ref: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#notes